# PC server, Android client. UDP. Client does not receive packets from server

Tags: android, udp, java-native-interface, client-server

I have been able to set up my client/server program so the server runs on the PC and the client on the Android. Either an emulator or a device.
The server receives data from the client, but the client doesn't receive data from the server(all UDP). Eventhough the server is getting the client's address from recvfrom.
I want to make it work in both the Android emulator and the Android device(my phone).
I read that the Android emulator has a virtual router. I tried giving the client the ip 10.0.2.2 when running on the same computer as the server, but that didn't solve it.
There is communication between the client and server, it's just one sided.
Anything I am missing?
I am using Berkley sockets on JNI\C++ for Android, and winsock2 for the PC server.

Comment: Does the Windows server have a route to your Android device?

Comment: I discovered with packet sniffing that the Android emulator does receive UDP packets. But since it has a virtual router, these packets never reach my application on the Android.
I am not sure about the device.

Comment: Do you have telnet on your android virtual device? Try and `telnet theserver anopenport` and see if the connection establishes at all.

Comment: I am unable to install telnet on the emulator, right now. Because I need another account to allowe me that. I can try on the phone though, because I think it connected there too.
I believe I am able to send from client(Android) to server(PC), I am also able to make a TCP connection.
The issue is, I believe, that the virtual router of the emulator(and the equivalent on the device) is not redirecting the UDP packets from the server to my android client app.

Comment: OK, so this means routing is OK and that's one less thing to worry about. Does ping work as well?

Comment: I tried using redir add udp:4515:4515 from telnet on the emulator. In this case there seem that there is no connection established, the client is unable to send datagrams to the server. Although the TCP connection still works. (UDP use 4515 in my app, and 4516 for TCP).
I will try doing the telnet on my device and see if there is a connection.

Comment: I was unable to ping my phone either when it's on wi-fi nor when it use cellular internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

I was able to make it work! So UDP can work on Android both ways!
The issue was that select on winsock2 has the first parameter unused, while on linux\Android it is used and called nfds. Sending NULL to that parameter(like I did in winsock2), basically made select always return 0.

Thanks for the help fge.

Comment: How did you connect your android device and PC? Was it via wif or usb tether? If it is via wifi was it wifi tether?

Comment: Zak, PC was connected with Lan to a router. Phone was just using WiFi connected to the same router. Any valid TCP\IP network will do though.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering if you would post a link to source code on the udp packet receiving for android topic, there's a lot of questions with no simple answers regarding it. I myself can't find a simple program for udp packet send from pc to android.